# Android - Custom Button Transparent

Tags: android, xml

I followed this [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBQeTUNu_Kk)
Some how my custom button it's transparent, here is my xml code for the custom button and I can build but the app crashes instantly.

the exeprion is 
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.Button

```
<selctor xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="false">
    <layer-list>
      <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
        <corners  android:radius = "2dp"/>
        <solid android:color ="#BABABA"/>
      </item>

      <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left ="2dp">
        <shape>
          <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor = "#4A6EA9" android:startColor ="#4A6EA9"/>
          <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color ="#D6D6D6"/>
          <corners android:radius="4dp" />
          <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp"  />
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>

  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <layer-list>
      <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
        <corners  android:radius = "3dp"/>
        <solid android:color ="#4A6EA9"/>
      </item>

      <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left ="2dp">
        <shape>
          <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor = "#4A6EA9" android:startColor ="#4A6EA9"/>
          <stroke android:width ="1dp" android:color ="#BABABA"/>
          <corners android:radius="5dp" />
          <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>
</selctor>
```

Comment: where is your logcat??/

Comment: add stack trace..and related java file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing shape tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
                <shape>
                <corners  android:radius = "2dp"/>
                <solid android:color ="#BABABA"/>
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left ="2dp">
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor = "#4A6EA9" android:startColor ="#4A6EA9"/>
                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color ="#D6D6D6"/>
                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp"  />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
                <shape>
                <corners  android:radius = "3dp"/>
                <solid android:color ="#4A6EA9"/>
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left ="2dp">
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor = "#4A6EA9" android:startColor ="#4A6EA9"/>
                    <stroke android:width ="1dp" android:color ="#BABABA"/>
                    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```